# spring-hibernate transactional dont rollback

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

The HQL statement does not roll back when I use spring+hibernate, but `session.saveOrUpdate ()` will;

**UserService**

```
@Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private BaseDao dao;

    public int updateTest(){
        int i = dao.updateUser();
        int t = 1/0;
        return i;
    }
}
```

**BaseDao**

```
@Repository
public class BaseDao {

     @Autowired
     private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

     private Session getSession(){
         return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
     }

     public int updateUser(){
         int i = 0;
        /* String sql = "from Student where name = 'dengbojing'";
         Query query = this.getSession().createQuery(sql);*/
         Student s = new Student();
         s.setId(1);
         s.setAddress("1");

         Query query = this.getSession().createQuery("update Student s set s.address = '1'");


         query.executeUpdate();

         //this.getSession().update(s);
         return i;
     }

}
```

Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(HibernateProperties.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass=true)
public class HibernateConfig {
    @Autowired
    private HibernateProperties config;


    @Bean(name="sessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean bean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        bean.setHibernateProperties(config.getHibernateProperties());
        bean.setPackagesToScan(config.getPackageToScan());
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DruidDataSource source = new DruidDataSource();
        source.setDriverClassName(config.getDatasource().getDriverClassName());
        source.setUsername(config.getDatasource().getUsername());
        source.setUrl(config.getDatasource().getUrl());
        source.setPassword(config.getDatasource().getPassword());
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager txManager(){
        HibernateTransactionManager manager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        manager.setSessionFactory(localSessionFactoryBean().getObject());
        manager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return manager;
    }

}
```

Spring transaction does not support the HQL statement, the problem plagued me for 2 days, I saw someone with similar problems, but did not solve the problem

Comment: i did some tests and it worked for me.. what are your spring / hib versions?

Comment: really? Can you past your code? spring 4.2.5  and hibernate 4.3.11

Comment: just to be sure.. when you do the execureUpdate and throw an exception after that.. the update is still persisted in the database right?

Comment: yes,the update is working

Comment: My question is updated

Comment: Renate your transaction manager to `transactionManager` or specify the name of the transactions manager to use in your `@EnableTransactionManagement` and post your hibernate configuration properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some tests with exact same versions and configuration.

I have to say that the update is never persisted in the database.

As a workaround, if you can implement your functionality in this way.. try to:

- Find the desired Person entity
- Update required fields
- Do not invoke any other methods on the session object after that.. just leave it to the framework to update the changes on the transaction commit.

**Example**

```
Person person = session.get(Person.class, 1);

person.setAddress("1")
// other fields updated

return i;
```

Now, without the explicit bulk update using the `executeUpate()` there is no chance for an implicit commit by the provider.. This is theory so check it out.

Comment: Yes, if you do not use excuteUpdate () is not a problem, however, in some scenarios need to use HQL or SQL statement

Comment: I want to know, but I write SQL or HQL the transaction does not work, or hibernate itself does not support

Comment: Try to remove that rollback for attribute... it's redundant in you case anyway

Comment: Thank you, I think it will be the object of Hibernate persistence can be managed by the transaction, because I use hibernateManager

Comment: I think the class is fine.. its more about the method name if anything